# Kubernetes Nginx ingress trying to get the wrong SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, curl

I have a strange case. Context:

At the very first, the client was using our domain for their store, the URL was something like `somestore.eu.mycompany.com`

Then, the client upgraded to a custom domain, other clients did this without any problem.

We deleted the whole namespace with the old subdomain and created a new one with the domain.

The root domain works flawlessly, without SSL certificate issues. However the staging subdomain works sometimes, sometimes without an SSL certificate issue, sometime with this error:

```
$ curl -vI https://staging.somestore.com/
*   Trying 35.102.186.11:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to staging.somestore.com (35.102.186.11) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.eu.mycompany.com
*  start date: Mar 13 09:29:46 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Jun 11 09:29:45 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName does not match staging.somestore.com
* SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'staging.somestore.com'
```

Looking at the logs I can see that `nginx-ingress` still trying to get the old certificate

`kubectl logs -f -n ingress-nginx nginx-ingress-controller-55f88544bf-dk7ht | grep my-namespace`

> SSL certificate "my-namespace/tls-cert" does not contain a Common Name or Subject Alternative Name for server "somestore.eu.mycompany.com": x509: certificate is valid for somestore.com, staging.somestore.com, [www.somestore.com](http://www.somestore.com), not somestore.eu.mycompany.com

Why Kubernetes's nginx-ingress still trying to get the old certificate?

Comment: Is there no Ingress definition which now defines the old domain? I would probably double check that. If you exec inside Nginx Pod, you should find the computed config file on the root directory which you can cat and check to understand how Nginx is truly configured under the hood.

Comment: I checked all ingresses, I didn't found anything related to the old domain

Comment: This website  especifically runs behind cloudflare (grey cloud, only DNS)

Comment: Do you have more than one ingress nginx running in your cluster?

Comment: I have around 150 ingresses

Comment: Is there some way to tail the logs of all ingresses? If yes, I can see which ingress is accepting the connection beside the ingress that have the right certificate

Comment: Not the Ingress resources, how many ingress-nginx _controller_ is running in your cluster?

Comment: Where did you get and store the certificates? I guess `certbot` and the certificates are in the k8s-resource `certificates`?

Answer (score 1):

1. make sure you have the correct configmaps, secrets or other configuration in your cluster (E.g. where SSL certs are stored). The desired config must be present, the deprecated must be dumped.
2. perform a rollout restart on your deployment. ( E.g. if `nginx-ingress` is the name of the deployment in the `ingress` namespace, do this: `kubectl rollout restart -n ingress deploy/nginx-ingress` )

Comment: What rollout will do? This is a cluster in production

Comment: It will gracefully restart all pods in that deployment one-by-one without service outage. I'm not saying that you should not try your changes in a dev cluster before doing this, but if you don't have any dev environments, the rollout restart is probably one of your best options because it is meant to be a tool for zero-downtime change management.